# How do you sell Lego on Brickowl?

Tags: shopping, brickowl

I was trying to start a store on Brickowl, but I noticed that, unlike Bricklink, it did not contain a sell button that was in plain sight. I searched around for it, but could not find it. If somebody could help me, That would be great.

Answer (score 5):

"[Creating a Store](https://www.brickowl.com/help/creating-a-store)" article, found on BrickOwl's Help section, explains pretty much the entire process in details.

Comment: On the page, it says there is a link at the bottom though I can't see it.

Comment: Never mind, I found it. Thanks for the help!